# How to get a string between a variable string and a constant string multiple times

Tags: c#, regex

I loaded a RTF file to a RichTextBox variable. This file has multiple-choice test questions. Each question consists of three parts: the stem, which asks the question,  a correct response, and four alternative responses which are incorrect.

I am struggling with how to get the stem, i.e. the question itself. The stem is  between a integer number followed by a dot  (e.g. 1., 2., 3., 4. etc.) and  the first alternative "A)". The stem has multiple lines including line breaks.

I don't kwow how many questions are in the file I am reading. Example:

```
1. AAAAA
AAAAA:

A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
E) 5

Answer: C
Explanation: EEEEE

2. BBBBB

BBBBB?

A) yyy
B) xxx
C) zzz
D) kkk
E) jjj

Answer: A
Explanation: TTTTTTT
```

I have created a class named "question":

```
private string stem { get; set; }
private List<string> alternatives { get; set; }
private char answer { get; set; }
private string explanation { get; set; }
```

I really don't know how to store each part of a question properly into a question object for every question in the file. Something like that:

```
question[1].steam = "BBBBB BBBBB?"
question[1].alternatives = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
question[1].answer = 'C'
question[1].explanation = "EEEEE"

question[2].steam = "AAAAA AAAAA:"
question[2].alternatives = {'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'kkk', 'jjj'}
question[2].answer = 'A'
question[2].explanation = "TTTTTTT"
```

I have searched for and tried to learn RegEx. I also used unsuccessfully many different RegEx just to get the stem, such as: (?=A))(.*\n)+(?=\d. ), (?<=\d. )(.*\n)+(?=A)). To test them, I am using the website: http://regexstorm.net/tester.

Please could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to get those 3 parts: the stem, question and first alternative A,  is to use 3 capturing groups.

```
^(\d+\. .*)\r?\n((?:(?![A-Z]\)).*\r?\n)*)\r?\n\s*([A-Z]\).*)
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+\. .*)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits, a dot, space and the rest of the line
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:(?![A-Z]\)).*\r?\n)*` Match all lines that do not start with an uppercase char A-Z followed by `)`
- `)` Close group 2
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `[A-Z]\).*` Match a char A-Z and `)` followed by the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 3

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%2b%5c.+.*%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5bA-Z%5d%5c%29%29.*%5cr%3f%5cn%29*%29%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%28%5bA-Z%5d%5c%29.*%29&i=1.+AAAAA%0d%0aAAAAA%3a%0d%0a%0d%0aA%29+1%0d%0aB%29+2%0d%0aC%29+3%0d%0aD%29+4%0d%0aE%29+5%0d%0a%0d%0aAnswer%3a+C%0d%0aExplanation%3a+EEEEE%0d%0a%0d%0a2.+BBBBB%0d%0a%0d%0aBBBBB%3f%0d%0a%0d%0aA%29+y%0d%0aB%29+x%0d%0aC%29+z%0d%0aD%29+k%0d%0aE%29+j%0d%0a%0d%0aAnswer%3a+A%0d%0aExplanation%3a+TTTTTTT&o=m) *(click on the Table tab)*

Comment: The fourth bird, thank you very much. Your regex is incredible. But is it possible not to get first alternative A? I only need to capture the stem. So I edited your regex to delete the group 3: (\d+\. .*)\r?\n((?:(?![A-Z]\)).*\r?\n)*)\r?\n\s*

Comment: @polarbear Do you mean like this with 2 capturing groups? https://regex101.com/r/PYqfmL/1 Or like this with a single match only? https://regex101.com/r/E5RbjP/1

Comment: The regex in https://regex101.com/r/PYqfmL/1 is working. Thank you!